# Zabbix JMX monitoring with agent auto-registration

Tags: jmx, zabbix

I can see how to configure a jmx server for a host using the zabbix UI.  I must enter the host IP address and port.

My use case has many aws ec2 instances that come and go according to scaling requirements, so I want these instances to auto-register with the zabbix server.  I can find no way to get these instances to tell the zabbix server to monitor their jmx server.

So in summary, how does a zabbix agent say to the zabbix server "my jmx server is at this IP address and on this port"?

I am using zabbix 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy solution for this afaik.
However, it can be done mostly on the Zabbix server side using some scripting.

If you can make sure the agent sends the JMX data in it's [metadata](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/discovery/auto_registration#using_host_metadata) when auto registrating, you can parse that data to a script using the {HOST.METADATA} [macro](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location?s[]=metadata). The script can then create a JMX interface on the host via the Zabbix API.

I don't have a script ready for this, but it should be relatively easy to setup.

Good luck!

Raymond

Comment: The issue is on the Zabbix dev roadmap: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1212